# Merry-Go-Round Angular Momentum Conservation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

[image]

For the above problem, I am struggling to conceptualize why $w_3$ is used for the last term of equation b) instead of $w_2$. My thoughts initially would be that, as child B jumps off the merry-go, he would attain velocity $w_2 * 0.75 + 2$, as he is initially travelling at the speed of a point at the edge of the merry-go, and adds 2m/s to that velocity.

My only reasoning could be something to do with the impulses canceling out only *after* he has jumped, meaning his "initial" velocity is in fact after the merry-go has slowed down, but I am not 100% sure.

What is the system for the angular momentum conservation being used, and why is $w_3$ used as stated?

Answer (score 0):

Child B leaves with a speed of 2 m/s greater than the final tangential speed of the merry-go-round (which depends on $ω_3$).  My question would be about the direction indicated as (n). Does child A retain her angular momentum or not?

Comment: I read that "child B jumps off horizontally in the $+t$ direction" (*tangential*). About child A: it jumps of in the $n$ direction. I believe they silently assume that it lands on the ground. @Gary what book exactly is this from?