# Angular momentum conservation with changing mass on merry-go-round

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, angular-velocity

[image: 1]

In the above image, child A jumps off at $2 \;\text{m/s}$ *relative* to the merry-go. The question for a) is to determine the new angular velocity of the merry-go, which was initially $2 \;\text{rad/s}$. The answers are presented.

My question is the following. For the left hand side of the equation $(H_z)_1$ includes the mass of girl A, whereas the right hand side does not. Since the girl is jumping off relative to the merry-go, she therefore has a velocity that does *not* coincide with the centre of rotation, and she will have angular momentum as a point mass.

How is it that her angular momentum is not included in the right hand side of the equation for $(H_z)_2$? And why is her mass only taken into account on the left hand side?

Comment: I disagree, they are asking two different questions, and someone had already answered the other one. I did not want to "invalidate" previous answers

Comment: Gary, I suggest to edit your [question] (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651252/merry-go-round-angular-momentum-conservation) from yesterday to keep every conversation about this problem in *one* thread. Also : is yesterday's question answered to your satisfaction ? And again I am asking what book this is from ? Please delete that stuff here and move it to the other thread.